# How to get pypi to recognise the OS correctly

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have a package that I have registered on Pypi.   However when I do `sudo pip install mypackage` from ubuntu it gives me the windows package rather than the linux one.  How do you configure your package to give the right version for the right OS?

Comment: What do you mean it gives you the windows package? Did you release pre-compiled eggs to PyPI? Can you provide us with a link to your package please?

Comment: `pip install` will normally **not** install eggs; it'll download the source release instead, and install that.

Comment: You have binary distributions as tarballs instead of eggs? How did you upload those? `pip` does **not** support such distributions and cannot distinguish between versions for platforms here. It assumes all tarballs are source distributions only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` does not support installing packages distributed as '"dumb" binaries'. Only source distributions, eggs and wheels are supported.

There are various other drawbacks to using dumb binaries, not least in that the Python version for which they were compiled is not listed, and they contain the full path to the files making these distributions next to useless to most end-users. Such binaries should really only be used in internal distributions where the target machines have the exact dependencies already present. They don't really have any place on PyPI.

Use `setuptools` and distribute eggs for Windows, *only*. For all other platforms, distribute just the source. If you are planning on providing a wheel distributions too, do so in addition to the source distribution.

Eggs with compiled C extensions have some drawbacks (specifically when having to support Unicode strings; Python has both wide and narrow Unicode builds and eggs don't record what version they were compiled for), so sticking to source distributions for most platforms is best.

Comment: Ah so to support windows (where it's unlikely a user will be able to compile ) is easy_install better?

Comment: @marshall: Use `bdist_egg` instead for binary distributions.

Comment: @marshall: `python setup.py bdist_egg` is the command produces a Python egg distribution; this records the Python version and platform. You need to be using `setuptools` instead of `distutils` for that command to be available.

Comment: @marshall: I haven't used Wheel yet, but I don't see why it wouldn't be worth using. It's easy enough to try out `python setup.py bdist_wheel` instead. :-)

Comment: In my case installation is long and complex and requires a lot of third party tools, and between 10 and 30 minutes of compilation. Is there some way to include binaries but still be able to automatically get the right OS version?

Comment: @marshall: With a wheel or an egg, yes.

Comment: How do you do that in an egg?  I mean how to do you get it to automatically get the right OS version?

Comment: Eggs are created *per* OS; their name includes that information and tools like PIP look for that.

Comment: Yes, you do need to remove the dumb binary files.

Comment: What do you mean? Which files at that link are still dumb binary files?  They all have "Python egg" as the type currently.

Comment: Also.. everything on that page is 3060 but it is downloading 3030.  pip -v shows `Downloading/unpacking ortools
  Using version 1.3030.win32 (newest of versions: 1.3030.win32, 1.3030.win-amd64, 1.3030.macosx-10.9-intel, 1.3030.linux-x86_64, 1.3030.linux-i686)`. So it seems to be ignored the filenames completely.

Comment: Interesting; those egg names look wrong. Can you share the setup.py file?

Comment: You now have what look like actual eggs on your PyPI page; it is still not working?

Comment: Ah pip can't install egg files. sudo easy_install ortools worked!

Comment: It can install eggs too but you need to use a command line switch to do so: `pip install --egg ortools`

Comment: Interesting! That option is not listed in the man page of pip 1.3.1 and http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/other-tools.html says "It cannot install from eggs."

Comment: See the [`pip install` options](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-install); it basically will take the egg and install it 'not flat'; not quite what `easy_install` does but good enough for most cases.